# For loop in route.patch does not work. || Exprees.js

Tags: express

Below is the piece of code for my route.patch function that I defined for /:productId

```
route.patch('/:productId',(req,res,next)=>{
    
    const id = req.params.productId;
    const updateOps = {};
    console.log(req.body);
    for (const ops of req.body) {
        updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
        console.log(updateOps);
    }
    
    res.status(200).json({Message: 'Hi'});
});
```

console.log(req.body) before the for loop is working but the console.log(updateOps) inside for loop is not working. And the even the res.status(200).json({Message: 'Hi'}); is not working . I am getting a route not found error.
Basically everything before for loop is working and everything after for loop is not working.

Can you please let me know where am I doing wrong. Is it the way I use for loop inside route.patch is wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does `req.body` contain an iterable, e.g. an array?

Comment: Thanks eol, I was passing a Json Object till now in the body. I forgot that I designed it to pass an array. Now my issue is solved after passing an array. But can you explain why its showing route not found when I pass a Json object? Btw I am catching errors in my routes.

Comment: Can you add the code for catching errors?

Comment: //error handling
app.use((req,res,next)=> {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    //console.log(error.status)
    //console.log(error.message)
    error.status= 404;
    //console.log(error.message)
    next(error);
});

app.use((error,req,res,next)=> {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error:{
            message:'Route not found'
        }
    })

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question regarding the error-handling from the comments. You have the following middlewares:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    //console.log(error.status) //console.log(error.message) 
    error.status = 404; //console.log(error.message) 
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: 'Route not found'
        }
    })
});
```

So for every request an error-object will be created which you assign status `404` and pass it on to the next middleware. There you send the error response and since the status is already set to `404` this status is used.

Actually you should just remove the first middleware where you create the error, as this would be done for every request. Express already handles requests to routes that do not exist and will return a `404` not found response. You can keep the second middleware to handle any other unhandled errors though (you should change the error message though :))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Answer and suggestion. You rock!! :))

Comment: No problem - please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left, thank you!